# Firefox 3.5 eating body margin on random sites?

Tags: html, firefox

Since a few days, I have noticed on several, not related pages that a few seconds after loading (maybe onload), sometimes (about 1 time in 50), FF 3.5 swallows the left margin of the body tag (I suspect) and the whole content moves to the left.

Reloading the page or re-entering the address will not help: The margin stays missing.
Going to a different page, and coming back helps: The margin is as defined, and stays that way.

I noted this on a few development sites of my own and initially suspected a CSS problem. Just now, I noticed the very same behaviour on a [large portal](http://www.koeln.de/) and I am beginning to suspect this is something universal.

Has anybody else experienced this and knows what this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I have not experienced this.

Could it be some weird extension that you have installed? Can you reproduce from a clean profile?

Comment: Good point. I have Firebug, FirePHP and Web Developer toolbar installed. I will need those all day so I can't set up a clean profile but maybe later.

Comment: You can start up a clean Firefox profile without closing your current sessions by running the command: `firefox -no-remote -ProfileManager` (if you're on Windows, just create a shortcut and append these switches)